# Umlaute get wrong when doing an update of a row

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I am running a grails V2.3.5 application which i brought to a new server and a new database server.

Migrated data is displayed correctly.

But when I update a row my German Umlaute get strange characters.

When I change the data with a mysql client it is displayed correctly again.

Any Idea what that could be and where i could look at?

Comment: Read about encoding and collation: https://techbriefers.com/how-to-choose-your-mysql-encoding-and-collation/ 
Especially MySQL use weird (Swedish) default encoding which might be a root cause of your trouble.

Comment: oh, and remember to establish proper connection with explicit encoding with your db similar to `url: jdbc:mysql://SERVER_DOMAIN:3306/DATABASE_NAME?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem it was not related to grails. I missed a tomcat configuration in

server.xml

```
 URIEncoding="UTF-8"
```

in

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
        URIEncoding="UTF-8"
        connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```